# Let $G$ be a graph with order $n\geq 3$ and $d(u) + d(v) \geq n-1$ for any two vertex no adjacent $u$ and 4v$

Tags: graph-theory

I neeed some help with this:

Let $G$ be a graph with order $n\geq 3$ and $d(u) + d(v) \geq n-1$ for any two vertex no adjacent $u$ and $v$. Show that $G$ has a hamiltonian path ( not a hamiltonian cycle)

I really apreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: This is Ore's theorem

Comment: Yeah but Ore's theorem is $d(u)+d(v) \geq n$ so I don't know how to begin or how can i use it @JorgeFernándezHidalgo

Answer (score 3):

You add a new vertex $w_0$ to your graph and connect it with all other vertices. This new graph $H$ has $n+1$ vertices and $d_H(u)+d_H(v) \geq (n-1)+2 = n+1$ for all vertices $\not= w_0$; otherwise $d_H(w_0)+d_H(v) \geq n+1$. So, by Ore's theorem we see that $H$ has a hamiltonian cycle $C$. Now, we delete $w_0$ from $H$ and from $C$ and we get the sought-after hamiltonian path $C - w_0$ in $G$.